# get-wmiobject script not working

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I am trying to write a script to pull software list down from multiple computers in one script, however most is working but one field is not pulling through anything

I have got this script below...

```
GET-WMIOBJECT -CLASS WIN32_PRODUCT -COMPUTER CLUKxxx,CLUKyyy,CLUKzzz | SELECT-OBJECT COMPUTERNAME, NAME, VERSION, VENDOR | SORT OBJECTNAME | EXPORT-CSV "C:\CLUKxxx_yyy_zzz_Programs.csv"
```

the name, version and vendor is pulling through just fine, however I cannot seem to find a way to pull through the computer name. I have tried _SERVER, COMPUTER, COMPUTERNAME, SERVER but nothing is working.

I know the script is working pulling through software from both computers as I got duplicate program names in the list (i.e. IBM Notes comes up twice).

Does anyone know how I can put the computer name in the script?

So far, COMPUTERNAME column is appearing blank.

Thanks guys.
Dan

Comment: Have you used `Foreach-Object` before? This would still pull back duplicate programs for each machine that has them installed on, but you can then easily separate the results per machine at least.

Comment: Hi ross, I haven't actually used that before. How can work that within my script?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`PsComputerName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) property of WMI objects. Change your script to -

```
GET-WMIOBJECT -CLASS WIN32_PRODUCT -COMPUTER CLUKxxx,CLUKyyy,CLUKzzz | SELECT-OBJECT PsCOMPUTERNAME, NAME, VERSION, VENDOR
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but the column is still coming up blank when I export to .csv

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you getting the Computer name on console for the command `GET-WMIOBJECT -CLASS WIN32_PRODUCT -COMPUTER CLUKxxx,CLUKyyy,CLUKzzz | SELECT-OBJECT PsCOMPUTERNAME, NAME, VERSION, VENDOR`?